# select IDs with different names

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know there's a way to select different ids with css to apply the same style., but i can't remember how.

What i mean is apply the same style to the divs below:

```
content-target1
content-target2
content-target3
content-target4
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use multiple ID selectors:

```
#content-target1, #content-target2, #content-target3, #content-target4
```

If you don't want to repeat the ID selectors, and/or you want to match them only by their common prefix, you can use an attribute selector instead (losing a bit of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), as ID selectors don't have wildcard matching capabilities like attribute selectors do):

```
div[id^="content-target"]
```

Answer (score 0):

"#id" is how you select an id, and "sel1, sel2" is how you select either sel1 or sel2 for a rule:

```
#content-target1, #content-target2 { background: red; }
```

Comment: sel1 "and" sel2 in case both are present.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do

```
#content-target1, #content-target2, #content-target3, #content-target4 {
CSS HERE 
}
```

edit: forgot my #s

Comment: you need to add `#` for `id` selection